# Copying data from every 4th column in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a raw data with 100+ Columns in Sheet1 and I need copy every 4th column in Sheet 2. I tried Cell link, Just wanted to know if there is any formula in excel to do this activity.

Screen shot of sheet 1 and Sheet 2 for reference.

[image]

[image]

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In VBA you can use a for loop to iterate over some predetermined column index range and use `Step 3`. Column A index = 1 and Column J index = 10. So `For i = 1 to 10 Step 3` although you will likely want some kind of dynamic index rather the hard coded indexes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LR As Long
    Dim LC As Long
    Dim LC2 As Long
    Dim i As Long

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 1 To LC Step 3
            LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
            LC2 = Sheet2.Cells(1, Sheet2.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            If LC2 = 1 And Sheet2.Range("A1").Value = "" Then
                .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(LR, i)).Copy
                    Sheet2.Cells(1, LC2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            Else: .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(LR, i)).Copy
                    Sheet2.Cells(1, LC2 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
            End If
        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working like a Gem.... Thanks a ton for your help. If I want to copy every 3rd column or 5th column, what changes I need to make?

Comment: Got I just need to play around with Step 3 or Step 5.... You made my day... Thanks a ton again. Have a great day!

Comment: @Ganesh exactly.you should change Step number.glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

This is dynamic by both rows and columns.

This assumes `Column A` on both sheets is a good indicator of where the last row can be found.

---

```
Sub Columns()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim LR As Long, LC As Long, LR2 As Long, Counter As Long, CopyRange As Range

LR = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LC = ws1.Cells(1, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
LR2 = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
Counter = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To LC Step 3
        ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, i), ws1.Cells(LR, i)).Copy
        ws2.Cells(LR2, Counter).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check offset out.. It works for rows and columns
https://exceljet.net/formula/copy-value-from-every-nth-column

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a formula, its basic form is `=OFFSET($C$5,0,(COLUMN(A8)*n)-1)` but that means that you would have to copy it down as far as required to cover the entire range.  A more permanent solution would be to use VBA.